# Where are pre-commit hooks installed?

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

There is a tool called pre-commit (see [pre-commit.com](https://pre-commit.com/)) that allows managing pre-commit hooks.  When I installed the eslint hook using [these instructions](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint), and I run the hook, it complains eslint has no configuration file.  However, when I run `eslint` it's not in my path.

**So, where is pre-commit running eslint from?**

I tried using `-v` to see verbose output, but I still see no hook repository path.  I also tried reading the website.

Comment: I've linked a canonical duplicate.  Generally you shouldn't poke around inside the cache as it's implementation detail -- you probably want to run `pre-commit run eslint ...` if you're looking to execute an individual hook

Comment: But I'm not looking to execute a hook. I'm looking to execute a utility installed alongside the hook. If I execute the eslint hook, it just gives the error message to run eslint itself.

Comment: ah, you may want `npx run eslint` directly then

Comment: thanks for the advice. i know so little about npm, npx, etc.